# Extracting certain text from within element

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract text contained within the first set of b tags inside a div.

I can get the source within the div tags using this code:

```
user = soup.find_all('div',{'class': 'userid ui-corner-small'})[-1]
```

This gives me:

```
<div id="postmenu_70080790" class="userid ui-corner-small">
<a href="/member.php?u=85569">
<b>username</b>
<img class="concat-general useronline" border="0" src="/blank.gif" />
</a>
<script type="text/javascript"> vbmenu_register("postmenu_70080790", true); </script>
<div class="usertitle">Level 8</div>
</div>
```

However, I'd like to extract just the text that falls inside the b tags within this div (`username`).

Can I modify the initial `soup.find_all` statement to do this? Or is there another method I should use to extract this text?

Comment: Do you need to use beautiful soup in the answer? Would simple web scraping work without the library?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I prefer to use BS, and the answer provided by @shaktimaan is working great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to do it:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
>>> data = '''
... <div id="postmenu_70080790" class="userid ui-corner-small">
... <a href="/member.php?u=85569">
... <b>username</b>
... <img class="concat-general useronline" border="0" src="/blank.gif" />
... </a>
... <script type="text/javascript"> vbmenu_register("postmenu_70080790", true); </script>
... <div class="usertitle">Level 8</div>
... </div>
... '''

>>> soup = bs(data)
>>> div_ele = soup.find('div')
>>> b_ele = div_ele.find('b')
>>> print b_ele.get_text()
username
```

If there are a lot of `div`'s (I assume that since you are doing a `find_all()`), then you would have to iterate through every `user` and do a `user.find('b')` to get the `<b>` tags and then get the text out of them using `get_text()`.

On a second look, I see that you are doing a `soup.find_all('div',{'class': 'userid ui-corner-small'})[-1]` which gives you the last element in the list returned by `find_all()`. In that case, you would not iterate over the results, you would just do a:

```
>>> b_ele = user.find('b')
>>> print b_ele.get_text()
username
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. This works great! I used `user_text = user.find('b').getText()` to extract the desired text.